# Can I concat a string and a variable to select a DOM element in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have tried Googling this question but no luck. Probably because I'm asking the wrong way. Any help is much appreciated.

I have variables `copy1`, `copy2`, etc. I want to iterate through them and select each one to check if it's contents has a certain number of characters. When I use any variation of the below, it will either console an error or output a string in the console.

```
var copy1 = document.getElementById('copy1');
var copy2 = document.getElementById('copy2');
var copy3 = document.getElementById('copy3');

for(var i=0;i<4;i++){
 console.log(copy+i);
 console.log("copy"+i);
};
```

Ideally I would be able to select an element and style that via javascript.

Much appreciated
Thanks All.
Moe

Comment: `copy1` , `copy2 ` are DOM nodes. What do you intend to do with the loop?

Comment: given the context of the code (i.e. none) `window['copy'+i]` may work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Agree with @jaromanda-x:

```
var copy1 = document.getElementById('copy1');
var copy2 = document.getElementById('copy2');
var copy3 = document.getElementById('copy3');
for (var i=1; i<4; i++) {
   console.log(window['copy'+i]);
};
```

Or you can use more simple example, like:

```
for (var i=1; i<4; i++) {
    var name = 'copy' + i;
    console.log(document.getElementById(name));
};
```

Or even:

```
for (var i=1; i<4; i++) {
    console.log(document.getElementById('copy' + i));
};
```

Comment: Thank you. Selected as the answer for simplicity. I ended up modifying this method to be `var name = document.getElementById('copy' + i);`

Comment: @Moe-Joe Note that `name` is a global variable that is a string. `console.log(name, window.name, typeof name)`

Comment: @guest271314 I've added variable `name` with purpose to provide more clear and understandable code, but it is possible to omit this var and use just `console.log(document.getElementById('copy' + i));`

Answer (score 1):

You can store the properties in an object where values are set to the `DOM` element

```
let copies = {
 1 : document.getElementById('copy1'),
 2 : document.getElementById('copy2'),
 3 : document.getElementById('copy3')
}

for (let [key, prop] of Object.entries(copies)) {
  console.log(key, prop)
}

console.log(copies[1], copies[2], copies[3]);
```

Or use attribute begins with and attribute ends with selectors with `.querySelector()`

```
let n = 1;
let copy1 = document.querySelector(`[id^=copy][id$='${n}']`); // `#copy1`
let copy2 = document.querySelector(`[id^=copy][id$='${++n}']`); // `#copy2`
```

```
for (let i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
  console.log(document.querySelector("[id^=copy][id$=" + i + "]"));
}
```

Comment: Thank you for that. I like the object method. Thanks for the additional syntax knowledge/intro. What does the  `[id^=copy][id$=" + i + "]` denote? What is the syntax called so I can research it.

Comment: @Moe-Joe They are `css` selectors. `"[id^=copy]"` matches elements where `id` begins with `"copy"`, `[id$="1"]` matches elements where `id` ends with `"1"`. Note also, that where the value of an attribute selector is only a number, for example,  `1`, the value must be quoted `"1"` to avoid an error `VM108:58 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': '[id$=1]' is not a valid selector.`. Where more than one attribute selectors are used `"[id^=copy][id$="1"]"`, the elements' discrete attributes at `html` must match each of the attribute selectors to match the element

Answer (score 1):

Since nobody has addressed your "certain number of characters" requirement yet, I thought I would.

You could always use jQuery or write your own $ method, which works as a document.getElementById() wrapper function.

Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fza0n701/) to see it in action.

**HTML**

```
<div id="copy1">01234</div>
<div id="copy2">012345678</div>
<div id="copy3">0123456789 0123456789</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
// Isn't this just a brilliant short-cut?
function $(id) {
   return document.getElementById(id);
}

for (let i=1; i<4; i++){
   let obj = $('copy' + i);
   let value = (obj) ? obj.innerText : '';
   console.log('value.length:', value.length);
};
```

Comment: Thanks for that. i always appreciate different methods for the same challenge. jquery ideas, always welcome. cheers.